# Does discrete topology have interior?

Tags: general-topology, discrete-mathematics

Our textbook define interior as: 
Let $A$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.
The interior of $A$, as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is defined to be the union of all open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that are contained in $A$.

Then if it's discrete topology, what's the interior of $A$?

Comment: "it's discrete topology" is not clear. Do you mean that $R^n$ is discrete, or $A$? Do you mean the interior of $A$ in $A$ or in $R^n$? The answer depends on these assumptions.

Comment: If $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ and $A$ is discrete in its subset topology, then that means that $A$ is a bunch of isolated points. Then the interior of $A$ in the standard topology of $\Bbb R^n$ is $\emptyset$, but the interior of $A$ in $A$ (with the subset topology) is $A$.

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the differences..

Comment: The interior of a set depends on what topology you're using. Do you know what a subset topology is?

Comment: What happens if R^n is discrete? and what is the interior of A in R^n?

Comment: If $\Bbb R^n$ is given the discrete topology, then the interior of $A$ in $\Bbb R^n$ is $A$.

Comment: if A is discrete in its subset topology, do we automatically assume that the topology of R^n is the usual topology?

Comment: I understand! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

In the discrete topology (at least according to the definition i know of) every set is "clopen" so the interior of A is just A, just as the closure of A is just A.